# How to activate oracle services?

Tags: sql, oracle, service

I have no idea, how to find and run my oracle services. I have sql developer of Oracle 19 installed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are no Oracle services on your screenshot, so I presume that you installed just Oracle SQL Developer which is a **tool** to access an Oracle database.

What you need is the database itself, which means that you have to download it from the Oracle Technology Network, read Installation Guide, follow instructions and install the database. Then you'll see services (which will, by default, start on computer startup. Otherwise, you'd just right-click the service and pick "Start" from the dropdown menu).

Once the database is installed, you'd start SQL Developer, create a connection and ... well, *connect* to user you chose.

I strongly recommend you read the documentation; it exists for reason.

Comment: Yes, I have no this db on my machine directly. But I have image in docker. The origin of my issue is that I try to connect via sql plus to "smth" and have an adapter error 12506. I investigated my issue and came to the conclusion, that I need to restart services. Well...

Comment: Do you mean you need to start the Docker service? Is the Docker process running? Where did you get the Docker image from ? If you acquire it from a legit source then that place ought to have provided some documentation showing you how to start and stop the Docker process.

Comment: @Anton If the issue is with Docker setup then perhaps you should tag Docker rather than Service.